# Is there a way to scale a fixed position background image without media queries?

Tags: html, css

I'm guessing there is a limit to how much an image can shrink while keeping its aspect ratio before moving its position. Right now I am using a background fixed image, problem is that on the small screen when image scales down all you left is only a portion of it.

```
#page-header2
{
    height: 200px;
    background: url("https://images4.alphacoders.com/848/thumb-1920-848687.png")no-repeat center center/cover;

    background-position: 0 -280px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

You can see it live on a codepen https://codepen.io/russiandobby/pen/YzKaVpL. My question is is there anyway to keep the astronaut in a picture even on small screens without media queries?

Comment: Hi @russiandobby. I have taken a look at your pen but there are so many different carousel, #home-heading, #page-header background images in play (I counted about 7) that it is more complex than it needs to be for the question. I would suggest you start by making a minimum viable pen and sharing that instead. You might just stumble on the answer when you create that too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use viewports:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background: url(../images/yourimagehere.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center, center;
```

I'm not a huge fan of viewports, but they do tend to work.... You might have to set the height to auto.

```
width: 100vw;
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to using srcset. Following is the example i copied from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
         elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
         elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
 sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
        (max-width: 480px) 440px,
        800px"
 src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```